# iOS App Doesn't Open First Touch

Tags: ios

Whenever I click on my app's icon, it animated the user interaction but doesn't open the app.

This only happens sometimes after I navigate to other apps can come back.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.

It was because the app was from an Xcode build and not from the App Store.